# how to add a custom template to joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, content-management-system

Can we add a custom template that we designed it with HTML5 CSS3 and jQuery to joomla,or we have to use the specific joomla templates?
if it is yes how? 
I am really confused in this case,

Comment: what you have tried..atleast try your self and share your research.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are stored in the /templates/ folder.
The key file is index.php but many other files such as css and js go in there too as well as helper PHP files.

You need to adapt your standalone template to link into joomla's cms and place "postition markers" in it so Joomla! can insert modules and the component to display etc. at the correct place.

Use existing templates for reference and this docs page:
http://docs.joomla.org/Template

and this tutorial: http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Template_Development